# How do I prevent getting an error upon rendering a object array in Vue

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I trying to render values from a object array.
This all seems to work properly, however I am getting an error when I dive a level further into the object.

```
test: [
      { 
        "id": "7AdzWm3eqzUDKN24xDhI", 
        "element": { 
          "z": 1, 
          "w": "215px", 
          "y": "58.901px", 
          "h": "724px", 
          "x": "80.8646px" 
        } 
      }
    ]
```

The following renders the values correctly without an error

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="d">{{test[0]}}</div>
</div>
```

Result

```
{ "id": "7AdzWm3eqzUDKN24xDhI", 
    "element": 
    { 
       "z": 1, 
       "w": "215px", 
        "y": "58.901px", 
        "h": "724px", 
        "x": "80.8646px" 
    } 
}
```

The following also renders correctly but also gives an error

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="d">{{test[0].id}}</div>
</div>
```

result

```
7AdzWm3eqzUDKN24xDhI
```

I am getting the following error:

[image]

Although I wasn't able to reproduce the error in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MK01111000/q3wg4r8x/12/) I will still provide a link.

The question is Why am I getting this error although it seems to work properly and can it be solved.

Comment: Try adding `v-if="test && test.length > 0"` to the div with id `d`. This makes sure the div only renders when there is data. Now it also renders when there is no data, and updates immediately when there is.

Comment: That solved it. Thanks Maarten!